# How to get Attribute in phtml file

Tags: custom, magento2.3

I would like to add a new product attribute to the file

> **Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml**

And

> **Magento_Tax/templates/pricing/adjustment.phtml**

As an additional data tag like:

```
data-new-attribute="(value of the new product attribute)"
```

How do I get access to the data here?

Answer (score 0):

**You can get attribute using block**

```
$_product = $block->getProduct(); 
$sku = $_product->getSku();
```

**or using  object manager**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$product_name = $product->getName();
$product_id =   $product->getSku();
```